# Solid mode in video editor

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, texture-painting

I'm trying to render a sequence in the video editor but the textures disappear when I go into the video editor and add the strips I need. I'm in blender render with the strips on the bottom track

Has anyone encountered this? If so, how did they fix it?

Comment: could you add some screenshots?

Comment: FIgured it out on my own.

Comment: @Zak please write an answer to your own question, it would help other users that run into the same situation.

Comment: Trying to answer it but the topic is on hold

Comment: And for some reason I'm not allowed to ask any questions?

Comment: @Zak about your not being able to ask questions, well you encountered an auto question block. That is triggered from low quality questions. Now only to get that lifted is by making good quality posts. (A good start would be for you to go back and edit some of your questions and make then clearer.) Now I have reopened this question so you can answer it, that will help too with getting the question ban lifted.

Comment: I have answered this question, and as far as the other questions go, I have asked them to the best of my ability. As I am new to Blender. If I was able to "Ask Better Questions" I wouldn't be asking them but figuring them out myself such as this one. And I also didn't know I had the responsibility to "make my questions more clear" when I have already done so to the best of my ability, or lack of time to make answering this forum of my life prioritys. I will do what I can, but act reasonably.

Comment: @Zak to familiarize with the site and make better use please take the [tour] and read through the [help] section. Pay special attention to this section: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Go to View- Properties - then under the OpenGPL Preview- change solid to texture
[image]